# Why do I get a DLL load failure when importing cv2 in Python with OpenCV and Anaconda, and how can I fix it?

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Intel\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\cv2\__init__.py", line 181, in <module>
    bootstrap()
  File "C:\Users\Intel\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\cv2\__init__.py", line 153, in bootstrap
    native_module = importlib.import_module("cv2")
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing cv2: The specified module could not be found.
```

Why this problem I have try to install OpenCV with Python 3.11 and Anaconda same problem occurs again and again.

how to resolve it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to reinstall OpenCV with `pip uninstall opencv-python` then `pip install opencv-python` or install it with Conda

```
conda install -c conda-forge opencv
```